# Button always trigger upon pressing enter in textbox

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Kindly help me with this, i have a page with left side user control and right side user control. left side user control has two text box and 1 button, right side has 1 text box and 1 button. 
Currenlty this error happen, When I put my curson either textbox1, textbox2 or textbox 3 and press enter button 1 always trigger, i want to trigger button 1 only if i put my cursor on textbox1 or textbox2 and press enter, button2 should be trigger if i put my cursor on textbox 3 and press enter.

kindly see the mock up picture - http://postimg.org/image/b1o8i8h3l/

thanks,,,,

Comment: Show your code. Not sure the link is safe to open

Comment: kindly post your code. Kindly. Kindly. Kindly.

Answer (score 0):

You should add separate forms to your page, like this:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="textbox1"/>
  <input type="text" id="textbox2"/>
  <button>Button 1</button>
</form>

<form>
  <input type="text" id="textbox3"/>
  <button>Button 2</button>
</form>
```

Comment: actually its a seperate user control that loaded in master page

Comment: Still, the best way to get the behavior you want is to make sure there are separate form tags around the inputs/buttons

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could you use a bit of javascript.  Perhaps use the onblur event on one of your textbox to bind the  keypressEvent to the required button.  Assuming the button is valid if there is text in the textbox